# Not able to connect with internet on Tizen emulator

Tags: tizen, tizen-emulator

I am not able to connect with internet on `Tizen emulator`, I tried opening websites on web browser of emulator but it is not opening. I have installed `Tizen sdk` version 2.2.1.
Can anyone please guide what is the problem, why emulator not connecting to internet.

Comment: what operating systems do you use? do you use any firewall on your workstation that might block connection? Can you connect to internet from within SKD (e.g. fetch Eclipse package list)?

Comment: I am using 32-bit windows 7 enterprise edition. Firewall is there in system but I am not able to configure it. I am able to connect with internet from IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out emulator is not having `DNS server` setting. When I type ip address of website in tizen web browser it opened up website. Now I am looking into how to make emulator pick up dns setting of my computer.